# _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exc_info' after updating packages versions

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I'm currently updating some packages versions in a project.
I'm using python 3.9

Here the new versions:

```
azure-ai-formrecognizer = "==3.1.1" to "==3.2.1"
azure-identity = "==1.11.0" to "==1.12.0"
azure-keyvault-secrets = "==4.6.0" to "==4.7.0"
nltk = "==3.4.4" to "==3.6.6"
numpy = "==1.21.1" to "==1.22"
tabulate = "==0.8.3" to "==0.9.0"
requests = "==2.23.0" to "==2.29.0"
camelot-py = "==0.8.2" to "==0.11.0"
tabula-py = "==2.0.4" to "==2.7.0"
PyPDF2 = "==1.26.0" to "==1.27.5"
logzio-python-handler = "==3.0.0" to "==4.0.1"
```

TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exc_info'

It Seems one of this version update is messing with logging. But because of dependencies could not figure out which one it is.

Comment: try them one at a time instead of all together.  the one that fails is the problematic one.

Comment: Found that setting numpy to "==1.24.0" solves this. Yes @D.L that is what i did, thanks for the advice.